# SUM of counts on dynamic tables as columns MYSQL

Tags: mysql

The following mysql query will output a column of usernames and a series of 5 columns after each user name which are the results of 5 counts.

```
SELECT f.username, 
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM sites s WHERE s.username = f.username) site_count,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM banners b WHERE b.username = f.username) banner_count,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM favorites fa WHERE fa.username = f.username) favorite_count,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM social_posts so WHERE so.username = f.username) social_count,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM stream_updates st WHERE st.username = f.username) stream_count
FROM members f
    WHERE f.username 
      IN (SELECT friend2 as username FROM list_friends WHERE friend1 = :user
      AND friend2 <> :user)
    OR f.username 
      IN (SELECT friend1 as username FROM list_friends  WHERE friend2 = :user
    AND friend1 <> :user) 
    OR f.username = :user
```

EXAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
| username | site_count | banner_count | favorite_count | social_count | stream_count |
+----------+------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
|  user1   |     7      |       12     |        3       |       5      |     11       |
|  user2   |     2      |        1     |        12      |       1      |     0        |
|  user3   |     5      |        7     |        4       |       9      |     25       |
```

What I am hoping to achieve for outcome is a sum of each row:

```
| username | site_count | banner_count | favorite_count | social_count | stream_count |
+----------+------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
|          |    14      |       20     |        19      |      15      |     36       |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to used user defined variables with := so that the variable would be updated with each sum.

For more details read: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

The ending result of the updated query is as follows:

```
SELECT f.username,
@sites := SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sites s WHERE s.username = f.username)) AS site_count,
@banner := SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM banners b WHERE b.username = f.username)) AS banner_count,
@favs := SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM favorites fa WHERE fa.username = f.username)) AS favorite_count,
@social := SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM social_posts so WHERE so.username = f.username)) AS social_count,
@stream := SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stream_updates st WHERE st.username = f.username)) AS stream_count
  FROM members f
     WHERE f.username 
     IN (SELECT friend2 as username FROM list_friends WHERE friend1 = :user
     AND friend2 <> :user)
  OR f.username 
     IN (SELECT friend1 as username FROM list_friends  WHERE friend2 = :user
     AND friend1 <> :user) 
  OR f.username = :user
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a sum to count?

```
SELECT f.username, 
    SUM((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM sites s WHERE s.username = f.username)) site_count,
    SUM((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM banners b WHERE b.username = f.username)) banner_count,
    SUM((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM favorites fa WHERE fa.username = f.username)) favorite_count,
    SUM((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM social_posts so WHERE so.username = f.username)) social_count,
    SUM((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM stream_updates st WHERE st.username = f.username)) stream_count
FROM members f
WHERE f.username 
  IN (SELECT friend2 as username FROM list_friends WHERE friend1 = :user
  AND friend2 <> :user)
OR f.username 
  IN (SELECT friend1 as username FROM list_friends  WHERE friend2 = :user
AND friend1 <> :user) 
OR f.username = :user
```

if need every user's counts, just Add `Group By f.username` to the end

Comment: Unfortunately just wrapping them in SUM won't cut it, I wish it were so simple. That will take the sum of each count for each user, which is useless. For example if a count returns 5 for user1, doing a sum of 5, will not change the result. Also group by won't work, as f.username and username from the IN statement, are not the same and can't be grouped as such. I have tried to do a group by f.username, also tried group by username, all result in no change.

Comment: ok, then ..maybe easy way to do this is count them out of sql.if use php just count them in php

Comment: That may in fact be the way to go but I am hoping for a sql based solution as I have to make the connection anyways for the data, and all the data is indexed, so I would like to do it in mysql if possible. :)